# Randomly add class to two divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a two column red/black grid 50/50% and height 100% and had a script to randomize the appearance of both when loading the page, so left or right. I changed the code behind the two column grid a bit going from relative position and float left of right to a fixed and absolute position. This has to do because of the scrolling behavior when in mobile this way it works nicer.

The code below worked fine when using floating it adds a class left or right that makes the red side choose a random side and the black automatically follows, because it is relative to each other. Using absolute and fixed position changes that it has to add to both sides a class left or right to work. Someone know how to add this so when red is left, black is right and visa versa.

```js
// Random red & black //

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // This is a ternary operator, which is just a shorthand way to 
  // do an if/else statement. This basically says, if the random number
  // is less than .5, assign "left" to the scenario variable.
  // if it is greater (or equal to), assign "right" to the variable. 
  var scenario = Math.random() < .5 ? "left" : "right";

  document.querySelector(".red", ).classList.add("" + scenario);
});
```

```css
.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.red,
.black {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.black {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```js
// Random red & black //

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
// This is a ternary operator, which is just a shorthand way to 
// do an if/else statement. This basically says, if the random number
// is less than .5, assign "left" to the scenario variable.
// if it is greater (or equal to), assign "right" to the variable.
var scenario = Math.random() < .5 ? "left" : "right";
var scenario2 = scenario == "left" ? "right" : "left";

document.querySelector(".red", ).classList.add("" + scenario);
document.querySelector(".black", ).classList.add("" + scenario2);

});
```

```css
.left { left: 0;}
.right { right: 0;}

.red,
.black {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.black {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
}

.red {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid absolute positioning in this case because you don't want overlapping here (it's not appropriate here). You can replace your CSS and JavaScript code just to apply single class for reversing. Demo:

```js
// Random red & black
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  if (Math.random() < .5)
    document.body.classList.add("reversed");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* set height to be minimum of 100% of screen hieght */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body > div {
  width: 50%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 50%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body.reversed > .red {
  left: 50%;
}

body.reversed > .black {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it is not ideal, but it works fine for now. If i rewrite it i would go for CSS Grid Layout i'm already using that for future coding and it is great.

Comment: @Pallum Why using CSS Grid Layout, why do you need 2D here? If you just need line of colors flexbox will work for you. By the way CSS Grid Layout also works in IE10+\Edge, you just need to use old syntax.

Comment: @Pallum But to be honest I would use flexbox here because it should work everywhere (except something really outdated).

Comment: You probably right here. I used flexbox a bit and jumped straight over to CSS Grid Layout when it was 99.99% supported by the new browsers. Your code looks really sharp and minimized what i like! If you can do it with less code it is always beter. This was build before that.

Comment: Oh and the big reason of using the absolute and fixed positioning is to do with scrolling. The red side is fixed (50/100%) and the black side contains content/text that can be scrolled up and down without the red side moving with it.

Comment: @Pallum OK, replaced my CSS now to fit your need. But still you shouldn't use absolute positioning here for `black` block.

Comment: Super great stuff! Don't know if you know how to avoid this: when in iOS Safari the address bar hide on scroll which is fine, but the red side jumps up and closes the gap when scrolling down and don't keep the height at 100%. It is a wel known issue.

Comment: @Pallum I'm not iOS expert at all. So when using absolute positioning you didn't have this issue?

Comment: Before i used a floating and relative positioning with scrollling on the black div content. This avoided the addressbar from hiding on scroll, but the limited the amount of space. All other coding absolute, fixed positioning etc and scrolling on html will result in jumping red side height on scroll.

Comment: @Pallum If this problem is specific only for iOS Safari I think you can ask separate question without Javascript.

Comment: Yes your right it is a different well known issue and question. Background jumping because of hiding address bar. Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a **hack** than an answer.

You add  `padding-left:50%` to `.black` and you give `.red` a higher `z-index` value to compensate for the difference in `position` settings.

finally I added `body {overflow:hidden}` -  *body happens to be the container in this case* -  to tidy things up.

```js
// Random red & black //

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // This is a ternary operator, which is just a shorthand way to 
  // do an if/else statement. This basically says, if the random number
  // is less than .5, assign "left" to the scenario variable.
  // if it is greater (or equal to), assign "right" to the variable. 
  var scenario = Math.random() < .5 ? "left" : "right";

  document.querySelector(".red", ).classList.add("" + scenario);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

.left {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.red,
.black {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.black {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 50%
}

.red {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
```